# How to fix generic dialog in validation prompt

Tags: validation, dialog, bixby

In a Search action I have an optional input with validation.

```
action (MyAction) {
  type (Search)
  collect {
    input (name) {
      type (Name)
      min (Optional)
      iterable
      validate {
        if (!exists (name)) {
          prompt {
            dialog ("Write the name you want me to look up.")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } // end of collect
```

I expect a prompt for the input (if not given by user) to have display and spoken dialog like defined in the validation  so "Write the name you want me to look up.".

Instead the display is the generic "I need a Name to continue" and the spoken dialog is both combined so "Write the name you want me to look up. I need a Name to continue".

I do not have any Dialog files.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it appears that you want the input `name` to be filled by the user. If that is the case, why not mark it as `min(Required)` and let the Bixby platform enforce the cardinality?

Overall, I'd suggest the following

- Create a custom type e.g. `MyName` with a `role-of` type `Name`.
- Mark it as a `min(Required) in your Search Action
- Create a View for `MyName` that will display your custom
  message.
- Create a dialog for `MyName` with the custom spoken dialog.

Let us know if this worked.

Comment: yes, that obviously works, but the validation itself does not prompt on a min(Required) input. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug.

Please report a bug via the `Contact Support` option in the `Help` dropdown menu in Bixby Studio. This will send us a diagnostics report along with your description which would help in investigating further.

Thanks!